# Why does ${3 \choose 1}$ equal to the coefficient of $x^1$ in the function $(1+x)^3$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There are three containers, each one can hold exactly one element.

Thus there are exactly ${3 \choose 1}$ combinations without repetition to put 1 element into those three containers.

This coincides with coefficient of $x^1$ in the function $(1+x)^3$, which expands to $1+3x+3x^2+x^3$.

Why is this so?

Comment: Do you know what Pascal's triangle is?

Comment: When you multiply $(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)$ you choose one of "1" or "x" from each factor. There are $3\choose 1$ ways to select which factor to take an "x" from.

Comment: there are 3 buckets and 1 element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we multiply three $(1+x)$s together, we have some $(1+x)$s that contributes an $x$ and other $(1+x)$s that contribute a $1$.

We choose $1$ from the $3$ $(1+x)$s and assign it to contribute an $x$ and assign the remaining to contribute a $1$ and ${3\choose 1}$ different ways of assigning will give the coefficient of the $x$ term in the expansion.

Comment: Also note that *all* such products (all $2^3$ of them) will be computed and they all have "weight" 1, i.e. every one of them contributes one $x$ to the total. So the coefficient of $x$ counts them, as it were. Hence the sum of the coefficients will be $2^3$ as well.

Comment: If the containers have a capacity of 2, the term would be $1+x+x^2$. Why is it like that?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, do you mean you want to find the coefficient of x for $(1+x+x^2)^3$?

Comment: @cr001 I'd like to know why the term was $1+x$ to begin with (for a capacity of 1) and why it becomes $1+x+x^2$ with a capacity of 2 :-)

Comment: The OP was asking about $(1+x)^3$ and that's why we are dealing with $1+x$. $1+x+x^2$ is never mentioned anywhere and I am not sure why are you bringing it up here.